# Row Number based on the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my results

```
Row     DocDate             CardCode    ItmsGrpNam
1   2019-01-23 00:00:00.000 C-SGD-1817  MH-PltTruck/Hand
2   2019-01-23 00:00:00.000 C-SGD-1817  MH-PltTruck/Hand
1   2021-09-07 00:00:00.000 C-SGD-1817  MH-PltTruck/Hand
```

Can the "Row" column can be based on the year. if same year it should be "1" for the year "2019"

```
   Row  DocDate                 CardCode    ItmsGrpNam
    1   2019-01-23 00:00:00.000 C-SGD-1817  MH-PltTruck/Hand
    1   2019-01-23 00:00:00.000 C-SGD-1817  MH-PltTruck/Hand
    2   2021-09-07 00:00:00.000 C-SGD-1817  MH-PltTruck/Hand
```

Below is my query:

```
select row_number() over (partition by o3.CardCode, o3.ItmsGrpNam, Year(o3.DocDate) order by o3.DocDate) [row]
    , o3.DocDate, o3.CardCode, o3.ItmsGrpNam
from OINV o3
```

Comment: Have you tried [`rank`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: DENSE_RANK() over (partition by T0.CardCode,T3.ItmsGrpNam,Year(T0.DocDate) order by year(t0.DocDate) )[row]. I have tried like this it is still the same all are as"1"

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the year from the partition and use the `dense_rank` function.

```
select dense_rank() over (partition by o3.CardCode, o3.ItmsGrpNam order by Year(o3.DocDate)) [row]
    , o3.DocDate, o3.CardCode, o3.ItmsGrpNam
from OINV o3
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8091cd6b8d407de0d9023269156c8b82)

Comment: `partition by o3.CardCode, o3.ItmsGrpNam`  often slow down the query.Partiton  on varchar column is always bad idea. Moroever in your fiddle sample I tested this 
 `partition by o3.CardCode, o3.ItmsGrpNam`  not required.simply remove it. Only `dense_rank() over ( order by Year(o3.DocDate))` will work